# Find the sum of 6 smallest natural numbers satisfying the following equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find the sum of 6 smallest natural numbers satisfying the following equation:
>   $$f(a)+f(a+1)=7$$
>   where $f$ denotes the number of all positive integer divisors of $a$.

I've found 8,9,16,25 by hand, but I don't know what trick should I use to solve it smartly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we note that one of $f(a), f(a+1)$ is odd.

Also, if $f(n)$ is odd, $n$ is a square number.

This results that $a$ is a square or $1$ less than a square.

This can reduce the time needed to solve it.

Also, the number of factors of each integer larger than $1$ is at least $2$.

So the number of factors of the square number is $3$ or $5$.

Can you do the rest of it?

Comment: Further hint: If the number of factors in the square is $3$, then the number of factors in the other number is $4$, which makes that number a semiprime. If the number of factors in the square is $5$, then the number of factors in the other number is $2$, which makes that number a prime.